# adb doesn't detect phone on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: adb

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 PC that sometimes does not detect my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 smartphone. The following error message will pop up when I connect the device.

```
Unable to mount SAMSUNG_Android
Unable to open MTP device '[usb:001, 085]'
```

USB debugging has been enabled on the device, and 51-android.rules/52-android.rules both have the device USB PID in them.

adb detects my Galaxy S3 and Nexus 5 just fine.

I've tried rebooting the phone, as well as killing-restarting adb, but still nothing.

Any help?

Comment: Install and run mtp-detect. And post here what it gives you. After that,try enabling usb charging instead of MTP, in addition to enabling developer mode. Use the actual usb cable that came with the device (if you can remember which one it is, not all micro-usb to usb cables are created equal). Don't forget to accept the RSA fingerprint the first time around. On my Linux laptops with Ubuntu 12.04, I actually have no trouble connecting to my Samsung Note 8 tablet. I'm really surprised it works with your S3 but not your Note 2. Is your Note 2 still under warranty? May be, the device is defective.

Comment: Also make sure you're not using a tethering app that makes use of adb in the background. And that you don't have a security app like "Lookout" running as well. A possible workaround for the short-term (that works better than email, or downloading the app manually) would be to root your device and install an app that allows you to do adb over wifi (assuming you're using home wifi which usually doesn't have wifi isolation running).